# OSX - NSImageView and playing GIFs efficiently?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

Has anyone been able to play GIFs efficiently on OSX using NSImageView?

FLAnimatedImageView (https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage) is great for iOS but there does not seem to be an equivalent for OSX.

I've resorted to rendering GIFs in a webview because it provides better performance than NSImageView with `isAnimated=YES`, especially when displaying multiple GIFs.

Comment: Great question. <bump>